# electron blank screen after build with vue-cli-service electron:build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, electron

I have tried the following things to remove the blank screen from my `electron` app:

(1) In `background.js` comment out `createProtocol` and `loadURL('app:...')` and instead use `path.join()`:

```js
if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
  win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
  if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
} else {
  createProtocol('app')
  // Load the index.html when not in development
  // win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'bundled/index.html'));
}
```

(2) Set router mode to `'hash'`:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: process.env.IS_ELECTRON ? 'hash' : 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

(3) Pass `created()` hook with `'/'` route to newly created Vue instance:

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  created() {
    // Prevent blank screen in Electron builds
    this.$router.push('/')
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Nothing of this worked, what else could be wrong?

Comment: I never worked with vue so this may be a vue quirk but the first thing I wondered about was that `app` protocol in your comment. If you have a built `index.html` (like after building a react app) and not a devserver in any kind after build, the `file://` protocol should work here. The second thing is, that in your code the protocol is missing - and in contrast to `loadFile()` the protocol is expected when using `loadURL()`. `path.join()` does not add any protocol to the path. It only adds the right separators for the platform you are running on.

Comment: @Rhayene I think you are right, I removed the comments on `createProtocol``, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could partially solve it. First I had to see some error message, which you can do by installing `electron-unhandled` and use it in `background.js` like this:

```
const unhandled = require('electron-unhandled');
unhandled({
    showDialog: true
});
unhandled.logError(new Error('Test'), {title: 'Custom Title'});
```

The message was:

> Error: Image could not be created from
> C:/Users/.../app.asar/my-tray-icon-2.png

This is an issue in the newest `Electron` version: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24221
It is unsolved yet, but what you can do it passing the icon path with `nativeImage` inside the new BrowserWindow instance like this:

```
import { ..., nativeImage, ... } from 'electron'
win = new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  icon: nativeImage.createFromPath('C:\Users\...\my-tray-icon-2.png'),
  ...
})
```